# Pandas: Access groubpy dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
#group by team and position and find mean assists
new = df.groupby(['team', 'position']).agg({'assists': ['mean']}).reset_index()

#rename columns 
new.columns = ['team', 'pos', 'mean_assists']

#view DataFrame
print(new)

    team    pos mean_assists
0   A   G   5.0
1   B   F   6.0
2   B   G   7.5
3   M   C   7.5
4   M   F   7.0
```

Hi, I'm having issues with accessing the first two columns.

I thought

```
for i in range(5):
   print(new["team"][i])
```

would be possible

Comment: `new.loc[i, ["team", "pos"]]`?

Comment: it does not work for me

Comment: Then what you want is not clear to me ;)

Comment: If you are going to assign it to a new variable, just do `new[['team', 'pos']]`? Or `new.loc[:, ['team', 'pos']]` should give you all the rows of the two columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the problem is. Below, you can copy my code (which should work). Hopefully you can find your problem from there.

```
new = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], columns=['a', 'b'])
new.columns = ['c', 'd']
```

Now you can either do `new[['c', 'd']]` or with a for-loop such as you did:

```
for i in range(3):
   print(new.loc[i, ['c', 'd']])
```

Comment: f'{new.loc[i,'team']}'
I'm using this with an f string. but always get the error: unmatched '['

Comment: You need `f"{new.loc[i, 'team']}"`. Note the different use of `"` and `'` here